# How can i restrict Texting in iPhone if it is in Motion of 10MPH?

Tags: .net, iphone, mobile

could you please give me some information For how to develop an application/Service for iPhone/Smart phone to restrict Texting in device if it is in Motion of 10MPH speed.

Thanks in Advance.

Bhramar

Comment: I'd simply suggest putting the phone down.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, without "special" apple support, an iPhone application is only running when it is the foreground -- and if your application is running then it might as well be an animated lighter and the speed of movement doesn't matter (unless, perhaps the flame should burn higher or something).

At least some months ago, this was the summation of the limitation on an iPhone application. If I recall correctly, a "lo jack" program had special support at the time.

Answer (score 2):

Use the GPS api to locate your iPhone at certain intervals, and use the location difference and the time sampling interval to get an estimate of your speed. When your speed exceeds 10MPh, you could restrict texting within your app, doing it all across the device is somewhat close to impossible.